# Wicked PDF not rendering remote image from php source

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, image, wicked-pdf

I have a php site that serves image content based on query parameters.  I'm trying to embed that image into a wicked_pdf and am just getting a little box with the alt name.  I've done the troubleshooting by showing in html and the image renders properly with the tag

```
<img alt="Doorsjpg" src="http://config2/doorsjpg.php?lineup=BR111">
```

I've tried it with both image_tag and wicked_pdg_image_tag and the results are the same either way.

Answer (score 0):

This wound up being a DNS issue, apparently.  Changing "config2" in the url to the IP address resolved it.  Couldn't tell you why it worked in HTML mode if it was DNS but it's been that kind of programming day already and I no longer question these things.